# Problem with scraping JSON data from website

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape this website for the data in the table: https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/overview/ESGV/portfolio-holdings

I have inspected the website and found that the data came from a JSON table through an external link. This is my code trying to target that link through headers and payloads:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import scraper_helper

headers = """ XXX """
headers = scraper_helper.get_dict(headers,strip_cookie=False)

url = 'https://api.vanguard.com/rs/ire/01/ind/fund/4393/portfolio-holding/stock.jsonp'
payload = {
'callback': 'angular.callbacks._m',
'planId': 'null',
'asOfType': 'daily',
'start': '1',
'count': '1527'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
results = jsonData['fund']['entity']

df2 = pd.json_normalize(results, record_path=['portfolioHolding'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2,index=list(range(len(df2))))
print(df2)
```

When clicking that link manually in a browser, an error pops up. "We're sorry. The page you requested could not be found." This is usually no problem. I have scraped several websites where the JSON data link comes up as an error on the browser but still works in Python. However this time, the error also comes up in Python. I can't bypass it for some reason.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You could try using postman to initially get the request working then move to python, if you're sure its a valid endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems their endpoint requires the `Referer` header to be set to `https://investor.vanguard.com/`.

Try this:

```
requests.get(url, params=payload, headers={ 'Referer': 'https://investor.vanguard.com/' }).text
```

I note that the response isn't quite JSON, the JSON is wrapped in `angular.callbacks._m( … )`.

Comment: Thanks! Also just realised I forgot to put my headers in the jsonData variable

Comment: How do I get the JSON data, instead of in text?

Comment: Store the text into a variable, say, `text`. Count how many characters precede the JSON (`m`), and how many follow (`n`), then you should be able to do `json.loads(text[m:-n])`. (When I say count, I mean literally get a response and count the characters yourself so we can determine where to slice the string.)